# OpenCover - cannot find PDB

Tags: opencover, nunit-console

I am having some trouble getting OpenCover to work

I have the following folder structure

- \Tools
- \Tools\Nunit
- \Tools\OpenCover
- \Buildartifacts

When my code compiles, all the compiled code is generated into the BuildArtifacts folder. This includes the dll's and corresponding .pdb files

I am struggling to get OpenCover to run

From powershell I am entering the following command from the root folder:

> .\tools\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user
>   -target:.\tools\nunit\nunit-console.exe -targetargs:".\buildartifacts\MVCControllerTests.dll /noshadow" -filter:+[*]* -output:.\coverage.xml

However I keep getting the message:
Committing...

> No results - no assemblies that matched the supplied filter were
>   instrumented
>       this could be due to missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter
>       please review the output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf)

I have looked at [OpenCover/NUnit can't find PDB files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586843/opencover-nunit-cant-find-pdb-files), and I have the /noshadow switch present in my targetargs

I attempted to move /noshadow to be the first in the targetargs, but then I get errors from nunit

I have also updated nunit-console.exe.config and added the following line to the startup node to ensure that all the tests are executed within .net4 instead of .net3.5

> <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319">

But that made no difference.

When I viewed coverage.xml file, even though I had the noshadow flag, it still appears that nunit is doing a shadowcopy

eg, this was present:

> C:\Users\darren\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10344_634940293912865718\Tests_275832668\assembly\dl3\db34ecee\a0f236ee_a7f4cd01\TABusinessInterface.DLL

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OpenCover WIKI](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/wiki/Usage) notes that when using PowerShell you should wrap the whole argument in quotes i.e.

```
-targetargs:".\buildartifacts\MVCControllerTests.dll /noshadow"
```

becomes

```
"-targetargs:.\buildartifacts\MVCControllerTests.dll /noshadow"
```