# Jenkins - OpenCover batch command cant find pdb files

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, nunit, opencover

I am trying to follow [these instructions](https://www.swtestacademy.com/jenkins-dotnet-integration/) for my system and am as far as step 8 (unit tests & coverage).

When I execute this command on the server it works succesfully:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" -targetargs:"C:\workspace\Extensions\Extensions\ExtensionTests\bin\Debug\ExtensionsTests.dll -result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2" -filter:+
```

If I add it as a Jenkins Batch command step I get:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" -targetargs:"C:\workspace\Extensions\Extensions\ExtensionTests\bin\Debug\ExtensionsTests.dll -result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2" -filter:+ 
Executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe
NUnit Console Runner 3.8.0 
Copyright (c) 2018 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse
Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000
Test Files
    C:\workspace\Extensions\Extensions\ExtensionTests\bin\Debug\ExtensionsTests.dll


Run Settings
DisposeRunners: True
WorkDirectory: c:\workspace\Extensions
ImageRuntimeVersion: 4.0.30319
ImageTargetFrameworkName: .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1
ImageRequiresX86: False
ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver: False
NumberOfTestWorkers: 2

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Passed
  Test Count: 37, Passed: 37, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2018-02-23 10:40:58Z
End time: 2018-02-23 10:40:59Z
Duration: 1.106 seconds

Results (nunit2) saved as TestResult.xml
Committing...
No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:
1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
guide and the -register switch.
```

I have tried setting the Jenkins to run under my ID and allowed it to interact with the desktop.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get it running please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh so I found the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381884/opencover-cannot-find-pdb?rq=1),  I just needed to move a quote to give:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" -"targetargs:C:\workspace\Extensions\Extensions\ExtensionTests\bin\Debug\ExtensionsTests.dll -result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2" -filter:+
```

Which works!